# Boot Loader (GRUB) disappears from BIOS Boot Sequence - Dual Boot Win 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Trying to install Ubuntu alongside Win 10 (UEFI), and the GRUB2 I installed on a separate drive (using this Wiki: [Grub2/Installing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)) disappeared after the first booting. My plan was to list the drive with GRUB installed, as my primary boot source in Bios Boot Sequence.

I have two drives, one of which is an SSD used for Windows and system files, and another (2TB) for storage. My Windows boot, however, is sitting on the 2TB drive, which got me trying to load GRUB2 onto the SSD and setting the SSD as the primary boot drive.

After installing Ubuntu, the option did pop-up in the Bios Boot Sequence menu, but when I tried to make the SSD as my #1 Bootable Device, the option was no longer there. I tried to see whether it stayed in the Boot Sequence, and it did not.

Is this a common scenario for Windows to block / overwrite GRUB and what would be the solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 5):

First, please understand that in EFI-mode booting, you don't typically boot from *devices* (as in boot code in the first sector of a disk) or *partitions* (as in boot code in the first sector of a partition); instead, EFI-mode booting boots *files* that are stored on the [EFI System Partition (ESP).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) The EFI boot loader to be used is referenced in NVRAM. I want to make this explicit because your question suggests BIOS-mode thinking that can lead you astray.

This brings up a second point: You don't have a BIOS. You have an EFI (or a UEFI, which is just EFI 2.x). BIOS and EFI are two *completely different* ways to boot a computer. Unfortunately, many people, and even manufacturers, refer to EFIs as "BIOSes." IMHO, this is a mistake, since it leads people to think of EFIs in BIOS terms, which leads to problems. That said, there are some crossover conditions. Most importantly, most modern EFIs include a Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which is a way for EFIs to use old BIOS-mode boot loaders. If the CSM is active, the boot path gets very complex, which can create confusion unless you really understand what you're doing. Nothing in your post makes me think that you're running into CSM complications, though.

What you describe is an entry in the NVRAM-based EFI boot manager that appears and then disappears. This can be caused by any number of things, including (but not limited to):

- **User error** -- You might have accidentally (even unknowingly) deleted it with a tool like `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu or the firmware's own user interface.
- **Program bugs** -- An OS-level program might have a bug that's caused the deletion.
- **EFI bugs** -- Many EFIs are buggy and can cause this sort of problem. You didn't say what brand and model computer you have, which may help confirm or deny this hypothesis.
- **Disk swapping** -- Many experienced multi-booters unplug one disk when installing an OS on another disk. Some EFIs, though, automatically remove NVRAM entries for boot loaders that are inaccessible, so this strategy can result in the symptom you're seeing.

In extreme cases, if your NVRAM-based boot manager entries can't be stabilized, you may need to resort to using the fallback filename of `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` for a boot manager. You can put GRUB there by using [Boot Repair,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but you must use the Advanced menu to activate the option to do this task. (I don't recall exactly what it's called.)

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that secure boot is completely disabled and Windows hibernation is also switched off.

Then click on shutdown(restart) and press shift key along with that and follow the onscreen instructions and boot into Ubuntu Linux.

Once you login into Linux you need to install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

it should fix your problem. Or at least you have some pastebin contents to be shared with us.

Comment: problem is that the only way for me to boot into ubutnu is through the USB stick with "try Ubutnu" option. Since `unbuntu` option is gone from Bios, I have no way to accessing it.

Comment: @Dimitry_N: I had a similar problem with the Suse distribution, and there I was able to get into my installed Linux with the option _More... — Boot linux from disc_ (or similar) on the installation DVD. (I then hoped redoing the boot options from `yast` would reset the boot information, but that did not work.)